# Reveal image on link hover with transition

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate [this package's](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2018/11/27/image-reveal-hover-effects/) basic functionality of revealing an image with some sort of transition/animation when its link is hovered.

I chose not to use the package since it comes with no instructions and implementing it into my work messed up more than it achieved, and it's quite heavy. I've accomplished the reveal functionality with some basic CSS, but I'm trying to add some sort of fade or slide transition to the image as it displays. I tried `transition: display 0.5s ease;`, but it had no effect.

```
<a href="#">
  <h1>Hover Link</h1>
  <span>
    <img src="https://edit.co.uk/uploads/2016/12/Image-1-Alternatives-to-stock-photography-Thinkstock.jpg" height="100" />
  </span>
</a>


a {
  position: relative;
}
a:hover > span {
  display: block;
}
a:hover > span img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
a > span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: display 0.5s ease;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzrKRM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `visiblity` and `opacity` Because, for `display`, `transition` cannot be applied. `transition` applies to opacity.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  position: relative;
}
a:hover > span {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
a > span {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <h1>Hover Link</h1>
  <span>
    <img src="https://edit.co.uk/uploads/2016/12/Image-1-Alternatives-to-stock-photography-Thinkstock.jpg" height="100" />
  </span>
</a>
```

It works incorrectly if `visibility` is not using also. As you can see: (without `visibility`)

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  position: relative;
}
a:hover > span {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
a > span {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <h1>Hover Link</h1>
  <span>
    <img src="https://edit.co.uk/uploads/2016/12/Image-1-Alternatives-to-stock-photography-Thinkstock.jpg" height="100" />
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Great idea. Thank you!